# Numbers of the y-axis missing in plot_ly()

Tags: r, plotly

I've done a plot with `plot_ly` in `r`:

[image: Plot]

Basically, it's fine. The only problem is that the values of the right y-axis are cut off (it should be 0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000). Is there a way to adjust the field or something similar?

```
plot_ly(scan, x = ~distance, y = ~Available_edges, name ="Available edges") %>%
  add_lines(colors = "blue") %>%
  add_lines(x = ~distance, y = ~cost, colors = "red", name = "cost", yaxis ="y2")  %>%
  add_lines(x = ~distance, y = ~cost_adj, colors = "green", name = "cost_adj", yaxis ="y2")  %>%
  layout(title="Distance scan",
         xaxis=list(autorange = "reversed"),
         xaxis=x, 
         yaxis=y,
         yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", 
                       side = "right",
                       yaxis=y2),
         legend = list(x = 0.1, y = 0.5)
         )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [Setting Graph Size in R](https://plot.ly/r/setting-graph-size/), Plotly has many layout options that may be of interest, specifically `automargin`.

> automargin (boolean)
>
> Determines whether long tick labels automatically grow the figure margins.

**Example Code**

```
library(plotly)


ay <- list(
  tickfont = list(color = "red"),
  overlaying = "y",
  side = "right",
  automargin = TRUE,
  title = "second y axis"
)

plot_ly()  %>%
  add_lines(
    x = ~ rnorm(10, mean = 50, sd = 25),
    y = ~ rnorm(10, mean = 50000, sd = 25000),
  ) %>%
  add_lines(
    x = ~ rnorm(10, mean = 50, sd = 25),
    y = ~ rnorm(10, mean = 500, sd = 250),
    yaxis = "y2"
  ) %>%
  layout(title = "Double Y Axis - automargin",
         yaxis2 = ay,
         yaxis = list(title = 'first y axis'),
         xaxis = list(title = "x"),
         legend = list(x = 0.1, y = 0.5))
```

**Example Plot**
[image]

Comment: Thank you! But it is not working for me. Even your code produces the same behaviour.

Comment: But manual margings work. Your advice should probably work in principle and finally you guided me to the solution so I accept your answer :)